# Can't read session variable value in ashx in Firefox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5, ashx

On login I am puttign user id in session variable then from next page I am sending a request to ashx. Here is issue I cannot read session variable here and get error message "Object refrence not set to an instance of an object". It works fine in IE but this error accure in FF.

My ashx file is implementing IReadOnlySessionState.

Comment: Disable Firebug. It probably messed up the HTTP headers.

Comment: The OP never mentioned using Firebug. Why tell him to disable something he's not using?

Comment: Can you post some code for how you're accessing the session when it fails?

Comment: what is the solution of this question????!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to have this on your ASHX file

```
public class LoginAuthentication : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

since you are putting the user id in session..

Comment: `IReadOnlySessionState` also works for (readonly) access to the Session. And the OP states he is using that.

Answer (score -1):

try the following links:

[Detailed info how to enable sessions in web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession.aspx)

[if you want to see example its here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service)